# Extjs : not able to display array properly. Always displaying as comma separated

Tags: arrays, extjs, combobox

I have a question related to the displaying array in the combo box. I am using extjs.
I am able to display array value in the combobox drop down but sometimes it's displaying as comma separated. Not able to add line break.

This is my view:  CodeList is an array list.

```
xtype : 'panel',
cls : 'item-text',              
items : [{
    xtype : 'combobox',
    margin : '10 0 0 0',
    cls : 'inputtext',
    labelCls : 'top-label',
    itemId : 'filterform-searchList',
    labelAlign : 'top',
    fieldLabel : 'search',
    store : 'TestStore',
    labelCls : 'top-label',
    forceSelection : false,
    displayField : 'CodeList',

    // vtype : digits,
    queryMode : 'local',
    name : 'fCode',
    grow : true,
    width : 130,
    listConfig: {                               
        getInnerTpl: function() {
            //  return '<div> ({CodeList.split(",")})</div>';
            var fArr = CodeList.split(',');
            var splitVal = '';
            for (i = 0; i < fArr.length; i++) {
                splitVal += fArr[i] + '<br>';
            }
           // alert(splitVal);
            return splitVal;
        }
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('TestStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

    proxy : {
        type : 'memory',
        reader : new Ext.data.ArrayReader({
            idIndex : 0,
            fields : [{
                name : 'fCode'
            }],
        })
    },

    sorters : {
        property : 'fCode'
    }
});
```

Could anyone please suggest me how to split displayfield value after render?

Thanks

Comment: The best and easiest way to set combobox values is to use a store (Ext.data.Store). How do you get CodeList? CodeList (in your code) should be a string like "element1,element2,element3,element n"

Comment: My store looks like this:                                                   Ext.define('TestStore', {
  extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

  proxy : {
    type : 'memory',
    reader : new Ext.data.ArrayReader({
      idIndex : 0,
      fields : [{
        name : 'fCode'
      }],
    })
  },

  sorters : {
    property : 'fCode'
  }
});                                                                                                                     I am getting CodeList from the controller. Sometimes I am getting value like "element1,element2" ,"element3" and so on.

Comment: Now I cannot help more, I don't know ExtJS3.

Comment: Thanks Michel. I will change from controller side and try.

Comment: Do you have access to ExtJS6 tagfield source? They work correctly, as far as I see. And please use `return '<div> ({CodeList.split(",").join("<br>")})</div>'` as your innerTpl, it should at least be far more readable.

Comment: Ah, please make a fiddle if you find the time; and provide the exact steps after which it is no longer working.